# How to allocate memory to array of character pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to allocate memory to the following array of char pointers:

```
char *arr[5] =
    {
        "abc",
        "def",
        "ghi",
        "jkl"
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << "\nprinting arr: " << arr[i];
```

Following does not work:

```
char *dynamic_arr[5] = new char[5];
```

What is the way to allocate memory for an array of strings?

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages, and strings and  dynamic allocation and arrays are handled very differently in the two languages. Please pick one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude C is a subset of C++, to be pedantic here.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Not even close. C and C++ might have some common syntax, but there are much much more that differs between them, especially semantically. Pretty much like Java, JavaScript and C#, all have some common syntax together with C and C++, but they are definitely not the same languages.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> dyn_vector(5)` will do it.   No need to use raw pointers or operator `new` directly at all.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - the code the OP has shown isn't even close to being C.   And, to be pedantic, C has never been a strict subset of C++.

Comment: @Peter Despite your statement, this can be done in a way that works in both C and C++.

Comment: The code you have already allocates memory. It would improve the question to give more background to the situation (and include a MCVE)

Comment: Also this code is invalid in C++, a string literal cannot initialize a non-const `char *`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - yes, I know there is a solution to the question, as asked, in both C and C++.   Catch is that techniques which work simultaneously in both languages are considered REALLY bad technique by seasoned practitioners of both C and C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ there are [more](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-strings-c-3-different-ways-create/) ways to initialize a string array. You could just use the `string` class.

```
string arr[4] = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

For a char array in `C`, you can use `malloc`.

```
char *arr[5];
int len = 10; // the length of char array
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    arr[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
```

Comment: Why would you suggest using malloc for this?

Comment: Well his tags were both `C` and `C++`, so I presented an option in C aswell.

Comment: Oh I see. Since you mention C++ in first sentence, I would recommend mentioning that your answer is for C. PS. Is it not considered bad form to cast the return of `malloc`?

Answer (score 3):

There is mixing up of C and C++ syntax and not sure if you are trying in C or C++. If you are trying with C++, below is a safe way to go.

```
std::array<std::string, 10> array {};
```

For completely dynamic one `std::vector` can be used.

```
std::vector<std::string> array;
```

Comment: Nice, I've removed my obsolete suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

May be below is what you are finding:

```
char **dynamic_arr = new char*[5]; //5 is length of your string array
for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
{
    dynamic_arr[i] = new char[100]; //100 is length of each string
}
```

But working with `char*` is very trouble. I recommend you to use `string` library in c++ to store and manipulation with strings.

Comment: This is a terrible advice. Lacks one additional level to qualify as a [three-star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: @YSC: Why did you say that is a terrible advice?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a C++ question, I'd advise an idiomatic way to handle a fixed/variable collection of text: `std::array` or `std::vector` and `std::string`.

> What is the way to allocate memory for an array of strings?

```
// If you have a fixed collection
std::array<std::string, 4> /* const*/ strings = {
    "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"
};
```

or

```
// if you want to add or remove strings from the collection
std::vector<std::string> /* const*/ strings = {
    "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"
};
```

Then, you can manipulate `strings` in a intuitive way, without having to handle memory by hand:

```
strings[2] = "new value for the string";
if (strings[3] == strings[2]) { /* ... */ } // compare the text of the third and fourth strings
auto pos = strings[0].find("a");
// etc.
```

Comment: since OP mentioned/ asked about memory allocation, you can also specify the range constructor of `std::vector<>` or may be the option for reserving memory using `std::vector::reserve()`